# Use IIS Express by default in Visual Studio 2010 (MVC3) web projects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

Just recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC3, but the only way I'm aware of using IIS with new projects is to set this up manually after the project is created.

Is it possible to click a checkbox somewhere to make IIS Express the default development server for all of my VS web applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS Studio go to options and in Project and Solutions select Web Projects. Then check the only checkbox available in settings: Use IIS Express for new file-based web sites and projects.

Comment: Do you know how to configure an old file-based web site to use IIS Express? I can't seem to find an option for it.