# How to test WCF service with TransportWithMessageCredential in VS2010 built-in web server

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a WCF Service with a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator`with a basicHttpBinding. This configuration, however, works only on HTTPS binding. Since Visual Studio 2010's built in web server does not support https, how can I test my custom validator? I keep getting `Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].` error and, if I set the clientCredentialType to none, the error is gone, but the validator does not get called.
Below is my configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ServiceErrorHandler" type="company.application.appserver.implementation.ServiceErrorHandlerBehaviorExtensionElement, AppSoftAppServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SimpleBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="company.application.appserver.implementation.AppSoftUpdate">
        <endpoint address="udt" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding"
          name="AppSoftUpdate" bindingNamespace="http://company.application/update/2011/04"
          contract="company.application.appserver.interfaces.IAppSoftUpdate" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="AppSoftUpdateMex" bindingNamespace="http://company.application/update/2011/04"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="company.application.appserver.implementation.AppSoftTransaction">
        <endpoint address="udt" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding"
          name="AppSoftTransacao" bindingNamespace="http://company.application/transaction/2011/04"
          contract="company.application.appserver.interfaces.IAppSoftTransacao" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="AppSoftTransacaoMex" bindingNamespace="http://company.application/transaction/2011/04"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
            httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <ServiceErrorHandler />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=" company.application.appserver.implementation.AppSoftValidacaoLogin, AppSoftAppServer" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use IIS for this testing.

Open your project properties, go to the Web tab, hit `Use local IIS` radio button. This manual is valid for VS2010 too: [Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-7/)

If IIS is not installed yet, install it first: [How to install IIS.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/)

You need to have Windows edition higher than Windows Home.

You will also need to create a self-signed certificate for your web site. This is easy to do in IIS 7: [Self-Signed Certificates on IIS 7 – the Easy Way and the Most Effective Way](http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test such WCF service in Cassine (built-in web server in VS 2010). You must use local IIS or install VS 2010 SP1 and [download IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb) which is lightweight web server for development ([can replace Cassini in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749508/use-iis-express-by-default-in-visual-studio-2010-mvc3-web-projects/5749584#5749584) and supports HTTPS with self signed certificates). IIS Express doesn't need any specific Windows edition and it works on all versions since Windows XP but it provides same features as IIS 7.5.

Comment: Tks for the aswer. @Alex's was a little more detailed, so I marked his as the answer, but yours helped a lot as well, so I gave 1 up vote for each.